# How to source sql file in windows for Oracle DB

Tags: windows, oracle11g

I want to source a sql file located in  "`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\malintha.sql`" location. I used following command in sql plus

```
SQL> @C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\malintha.sql
```

But it gives me

`Unable to open file` error.

How to do this correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it correctly but the file either isn't there or you have no permissions.

1. Double check the path
2. Ensure you are running the SQLPlus session in a command window with appropriate privs (perhaps Run As Administrator)
3. Try executing from a regular user directory instead of Administrator

I just tested a SQL file with:

```
SQL> @C:\users\msmith\desktop\test.sql
```

Comment: Path is correct but how to set priv for SQLPLUS session?

Comment: Open a new command prompt with "Run As Administrator", that is a Windows concept, not an Oracle concept. Right click the command prompt from the Start -> Programs menu, or type cmd into the "Start -> Run" omnibox and then right-click it to choose it.